# How do hashes get seeds/pins

Tags: ipfs, decentralized-applications

**I seek to understand how hashes (some images for example) would be pinned and/or seeded by users.**

Let's say I have my own gateway or I use the public IPFS gateway to retrieve some images. When for example a user goes to a website and this website loads some hashes:

- does the user automatically pin those?
- does that user also start seeding those hashes? (if so, where are these images stored and how could that user stop seeding)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of your situation, but I believe the answer to the first question is **no** (as of `v0.4.20`). Pinning primarily happens during the following commands:

- `ipfs pin add`
- `ipfs add`
- `ipfs block put`
- `ipfs dag add`
- `ipfs object put`

Regarding the second question, what I believe probably happens is (as of `v0.4.20`):

1. The images are retrieved via something like `ipfs get`, which does not pin, but does cause the blocks that make up the image to be stored in the node.
2. The node will periodically announce that it provides (seeds) all of the blocks that it stores.
3. Eventually, when you run `ipfs repo gc` (or if you have auto gc enabled), then the blocks that make up the image will be removed and the node will no longer announce that it provides (seeds) those blocks. Pinned blocks survive garbage collection and so stick around until you unpin and garbage collect.